# Tensorflow.io module is missing - how do I get gfile?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to use the `tensorflow.io.gfile` module to load an inference graph. When I try to import the gfile module, so I can get to the `GFile` class, I get the following results:

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> from tensorflow.io import gfile
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.io'

No module named 'tensorflow.io'
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.0.0'
```

I'm on MacOS Catalina with Python 3.7.4.

How can I successfully import sub-modules of `tensorflow.io` if it's missing?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pip install tensorflow.io
```

Should solve the problem.

The answer relies on the assumption that you are using TF2.0, in which this functionality has been moved to a separate package.